# Ansible execute task on different hosts in order

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to use ansible to manage order of programs?
Im trying to find an automated solution which will do the following steps:

1. run a program on HostA
2. run a command on HostB which requires HostA program to run
3. run a program on HostC if 2. step succeed
4. run a command on HostD which requires HostC program to run
5. run a command on HostE which requires HostC program to run

For example:

```
---
  - hosts: neededhosts
    roles:
      - startprogram
      - runcommand
      - startsecprgoram
    .
    .
    .
```

```
startprogram:
- name: start hostA program
  tasks:
    - name: start program
      hosts: HostA
      shell: /etc/init.d/HostAprogram.sh start
```

```
runcommand:
- name: run command on HostB
  tasks:
    - name: run command
      hosts: HostB
      shell: command which using host A
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q: *"**Is it possible to use Ansible to manage the order of programs?**"*

A: Yes. It's possible. For example, the playbook below does the job

```yaml
- hosts: HostA
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: startprogram

- hosts: HostB
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: runcommand
      when: hostvars.HostA.HostAprogram_started|default(false)

- hosts: HostC
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: startsecprogram
      when: hostvars.HostB.HostBcommand_passed|default(false)

- hosts: HostD,HostE
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: command on {{ inventory_hostname }} which requires HostC program to run
      when: hostvars.HostC.HostCprogram_started|default(false)
```

---

Example of the roles for the purpose of testing

```yaml
shell> cat roles/startprogram/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: /etc/init.d/HostAprogram.sh start
- set_fact:
    HostAprogram_started: true

shell> cat roles/runcommand/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: command which using host A
- set_fact:
    HostBcommand_passed: true

shell> cat roles/startsecprogram/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: /etc/init.d/HostCprogram.sh start
- set_fact:
    HostCprogram_started: true
```

Example of the output

```yaml
ok: [HostA] => {
    "msg": "/etc/init.d/HostAprogram.sh start"
}
ok: [HostB] => {
    "msg": "command which using host A"
}
ok: [HostC] => {
    "msg": "/etc/init.d/HostCprogram.sh start"
}
ok: [HostD] => {
    "msg": "command on HostD which requires HostC program to run"
}
ok: [HostE] => {
    "msg": "command on HostE which requires HostC program to run"
}
```